# Efficiently transfer screenshots from Ipad to Windows computer?

Tags: ios, ipad, windows, ms-office, screen-capture

I write a Word documents on a windows 10 computer and want to include screenshots from my iPad. Idea is to make something on my iPad, take a screenshot and directly paste it in my word document. I can connect the iPad via cable to my windows computer or access the iPad on the network from my windows computer.

Is there any comfortable way to get a taken screenshot in my windows clipboard, so I can easily paste it into my Word document?

Comment: Not aware of any clipboard sharing apps that work between iOS and Windows, but a free cloud storage account (Dropbox, etc.) would allow you to save files from the iPad and have them show up on your Windows PC.

Comment: @SteveChambers I just learned that there is iCloud for Windows :-) So getting the files to my computer is easy, yet I have to put them in the clipboard manually. But I fear there is really no better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple solves this problem with cloud sync and so does Microsoft. That would be the easiest way to set up a group of people with this in my experience. Even for one person, it works well for me so I can avoid pairing the iOS device with windows USB for ingestion of images in bulk. Also, the Files app on iPad is very good, you can save to USB and natively connect to all manner of sync services online for file transfer and sync.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204283 (iCloud for windows FTW)
- https://products.office.com/en-us/word (office suite have common code base now between Mac and iOS and windows even though not all features are enabled everywhere)

Also the iOS [OneDrive](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-onedrive/id477537958) and [Teams](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-teams/id1113153706) apps are pretty awesome for file transfer and sync. Even with handoff, clipboard sync of images can be troublesome on macOS so I would look for a different workflow if possible.

Comment: using icloud for windows worked best for me. one can just copy the new file in the clipboard and when one pastes it on Word, it directly inserts the image, not the file itself :-)

Comment: Yes @stefan.at.wpf I added an FTW to the iCloud link.